# Not able to create URL using getClass.getResource of an image in the web content folder

Tags: java, servlets

I have an image in web contents folder of path /images/car.bmp 
when i try to create URL of this image from a java class

```
URL url=getClass().getResource("/images/car.bmp");
```

i am getting null, why is that??

The directory structure is

[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnYfD.jpg)

Comment: The structure of your .war file is what matters when you run.  Is car.bmp in it?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to load the resource from the class path and the image is not present on the class path.

If you want a URL for the image you want `ServletConext#getResource(String path)` where path is going to be `/images/car.bmp`.